# exposing backend docker container via ngrok

Tags: docker, ngrok

I have dockerized my expo react native app (both frontend and backend).

And I am able to load react native app to my mobile phone (using expo).

However, how can the mobile app send a request to backend docker container?

Previously, without docker container, I ran the server on localhost:3000 and ran ngrok with the following command and mobile app was able to communicates to the backend using the URL provided by ngrok

```
// worked without docker
ngrok http 3000
```

I tried the following steps but didn't work. Both containers successfully run but the connection failed

```
docker container run -p 3000:3000 --rm --name backend myapp-backend
docker run --rm -d -p 4040 --link backend:http --name ngrok -e NGROK_PORT=3000 wernight/ngrok
```

This is the link I followed

https://github.com/wernight/docker-ngrok

Comment: From your computer browser or HTTP client, can you access the backend on port 3000?

Comment: yes. localhost:3000 works totally fine

Comment: So you don't really need to run `ngrok` in a docker container. I suggest to continue using ngrok natively in your host machine. I don't see why `ngrok http 3000` wouldn't work.

Comment: because I don't want to install those on my local setup. I want to use docker for everything so anyone can easily run it

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.
The command should have been like this.

```
docker run --rm -it -d -p 4040 --link backend --name ngrok  wernight/ngrok ngrok http backend:3000
```